# Ubuntu12.04: How to disable a daemon process at startup

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, upstart

I normally use `service start/stop` or `initctl start/stop` to start or stop a daemon process but now what I am looking for is to disable a daemon process from starting at startup example `mysqld`.

Currently what am doing is renaming `/etc/init/mysql.conf` to `/etc/init/mysql.conf.bak` but after reading a little about `systemd` I came to know that it provides `enable & disable` option for the above task.

So, is there something similar in ubuntu 12.04 with `upstart`.

Comment: You say you are using systemd? I use it on my Fedora 17 computer. `systemctl [enable|disable|is-enabled] mysqld.service`

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: No I am not using systemd. I am using upstart because systemd is not the default in ubuntu 12.04/12.10.

Comment: oh i see now... Not sure what i was thinking.

Answer (score 27):

You can disable services by running the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f <service name> disable
```

[Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) excerpt:

> When  run  with the disable [ S|2|3|4|5 ] options, update-rc.d
>   modifies existing runlevel links for the  script  /etc/init.d/name  by
>   renaming start  links  to  stop  links  with  a  sequence  number 
>   equal  to the difference of 100 minus the original sequence number.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to down vote this and doing so without an explanation would be impolite anyway, so then just a comment: The question by @Noob pertains to Ubuntu 12.04 which uses Upstart (/etc/init/*.conf configuration files) for most system daemons (as mentioned by @Noob) while your suggestion only works for daemons started using scripts in /etc/init.d/* (the old SysV style). Edit: For the record, warl0ck has the right answer (thanks!).

Comment: The question is about a hypothetical or in-general situation using mysql as a particular topical case.  OP seemed at least partially aware of this answer, but it may serve posterity well to note that some useful packages don't and won't honor the upstart format (like webmin and many self-built from source packages around the time of comment).  That means this method can be a valid partial answer for context, much like warl0ck and Mark's answers do to address the particular point of the hypothetical mysql service installed with a package manager.

Comment: The -f flag is not needed.

Comment: This is for init.d, not systemd, which most modern Linux systems use nowadays.

Answer (score 20):

The correct way to disable and upstart service, is create a XX.override file,

`echo 'manual' > /etc/init/mysqld.override`

That way the upstart service will not get started automatically

Comment: Is this still works with `Ubuntu 12.04`?

Comment: @RSK yes, why don't you just give it a try?

Comment: I tried and didn't worked for me. Lemme try again and will update you.

Comment: No, it doesn't work on Ubuntu-14.04.

Comment: `@RSK yes, why don't you just give it a try?` I suppose, because it is very inconvenient to restart the system with "a try" to every advise from this page.

Answer (score 7):

@warl0ck has it right; wanted to add that this information is documented quite well in the Upstart documentation: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting

Specifically:

> With Upstart 1.3, you can make use of override files and the manual stanza to achieve the same result in a simpler manner [27]:
>
> `# echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.override`
>
> Note that you could achieve the same effect by doing this:
>
> `# echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.conf`
>
> However, using the override facility means you can leave the original job configuration file untouched.
>
> To revert to the original behaviour, either delete or rename the override file (or remove the manual stanza from your ".conf" file).

Answer (score 5):

There is also a nice piece of software to assist in this. Its called rcconf.

Just download it using:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
```

and use it with the command

```
rcconf
```

You get a nice (commandline) interface to disable/enable services.

Comment: This is not included on the system, so install more stuff woudn't be the better answer.

Comment: but really usefull :D

Answer (score 1):

Try navigate to `/etc/rc2.d` and rename what you wish **not** to run at startup: change the (initial, capital) "S" into a "K" (e.g., `S02mysql` to `K02mysql`). If you change your mind, just reverse it. I think the 2 refers to runlevel, in what case 2 is the default, multiuser runlevel. Probably that's where you have most of the stuff for day-to-day computer use.

**Edit**: Read James O'Gorman's comment below.

Comment: Yes '2' refer to the run-level. You can check your current run-level using `who -r` or `runlevel`.

Comment: That's true, `who --runlevel`.

Comment: While this achieves what you want, it's technically the wrong thing to do. In SysV init terms, 'S' scripts are start scripts and 'K' are kill scripts - i.e. S are run in order at startup and K are run in order at shutdown (or changing to a lower runlevel).

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman: Interesting, I'm on Debian, are you saying my "K scripts" are run at shutdown? Is there some letter that could be used to disable the script altogether, with no hazard whatsoever? (It is kind of practical to keep them in the same folder, should a new situation arise where you'd want them.)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Yes, `init` will be running 'KXXscript stop' at shutdown. You should either remove the symlink or remove the execute bit from the real init script. I believe Debian uses `update-rc.d` to manage this. RHEL (and derivatives) use `chkconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

With Upstart the service configuration lies in files in `/etc/init/`.  For example ssh is controlled using a config file `/etc/init/ssh.conf`

This file specifies the "events" which will prompt Upstart to start the "job".

To prevent a service from starting automatically, one of several methods can be used:
a) Rename the service.conf file so that it does not end with .conf
b) Comment out the "start on" line from the service.conf file.

In newer versions of upstart (since v1.3 at least) you can also override the start on line using a service.override file, so you could use:
`# echo manual > /etc/init/service.override`

Lastly you may also add the keyword "manual" to the end of the service's configuration file, eg via:
`# echo manual >> /etc/init/service.conf`

Note that this does not "stop" the running service, it just prevents it from starting automatically.  While set for "manual" startup you control the service using initctl, eg to stop and start the SSH daemon:
`# initctl stop ssh`
`# initctl start ssh`

Arguably the best documentation for Upstart is at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Section 11.44 covers "disabling a service from auto-starting, here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting

Answer (score 0):

Well, I must say that the statement

```
echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.override
```

is a little misleading because it means append the override file. I tested this on 14.04 with the network-manager and the following didnt work

```
vim /etc/init/network-manager.override:
start
manual
```

However this worked

```
vim /etc/init/network-manager.override:
#start
manual
```

So, IMO, the initctl looks for the first uncommented line and executes it.
Maybe I am wrong, but those were my test results. Inputs are welcome.